# Using `dplyr::na_if` with a probability to create missing data?

Tags: r, dplyr, na, missing-data

I'm interested in simulating data with a chance of missing-ness. How can I do this using using `dplyr::na_if`?

Intuitively I wanted to do something like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg = na_if(mpg, rbinom(n = n(),
                                 1, 
                                 prob = .5) == 1))
```

But I think this is wrong because `na_if` is really for matching `x` and `y`. How do I use `na_if` to create a probability of missingness?

(edit: Also if there is a better function for creating missing data in the `tidyverse` please let me know in the comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `na_if` here, just use `if_else`. `rbinom` is overkill also, `runif` works fine.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg = if_else(runif(n = n()) > 0.5, NA_real_, mpg))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why is `runif` is preferable to `rbinom`?

Comment: It just seems a little simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification of your code:

```
mtcars %>%
 mutate(mpg = if_else(rbinom(n(), 1, prob = 0.5) == 1, NA_real_, mpg))

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4    NA   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6    NA   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
10   NA   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```